# Unable to connect to Virtual Private Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to figure out what is going on here as I am unable to connect to a VPN most of the time. I am using FrootVPN on the OpenVPN protocol. I used [this guide](https://www.frootvpn.com/guides/windows-vista7-10.html) to set it up. It is entirely ran through software on my computer (running windows 7 64 bit) I have not made any changes to the router settings. I have been using it for about 4 or 5 days and at first it was working fine. Then it started needing 2 or 3 tries to connect and now it won't connect most of the time. I ALWAYS run as admin. Today I turned off my antivirus/firewall and now it connects but my IP address stays the same.

Logs: *Logs had to be uploaded because I met my maximum character count*

[Does Not Connect](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByGDeV45L_7LSE51NkF4OC1qR0k/view?usp=sharing)

[IP address does not change](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByGDeV45L_7LLWN1emJiamhBM0U/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT:** *If I was to add it to the whitelist in my firewall what would the address and port and all that information be?
Also Now I get an error dialogue saying "ERROR: Reconnecting to FrootVPN has failed*

I forgot my credentials to my router so I did a factory reset. That hasn't helped yet, I will try turning off the firewall just to test.

OK, With the firewall on the router turned off and the program ran as admin I get this:

```
Thu Jan 15 13:52:33 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.6 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Thu Jan 15 13:52:33 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014, LZO 2.08
Enter Management Password:
Thu Jan 15 13:52:33 2015 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Thu Jan 15 13:52:33 2015 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Thu Jan 15 13:52:33 2015 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Thu Jan 15 13:52:34 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Thu Jan 15 13:52:34 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Thu Jan 15 13:52:34 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Thu Jan 15 13:52:34 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'username "Auth" "dylan07"'
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'password [...]'
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1421358760,RESOLVE,,,
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]178.73.212.194:1201
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1421358760,WAIT,,,
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1421358760,AUTH,,,
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]178.73.212.194:1201, sid=3406ba47 85bdd4aa
Thu Jan 15 13:52:40 2015 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Thu Jan 15 13:52:41 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=SE, ST=QQ, L=FrootTown, O=FrootOrg, OU=changeme, CN=changeme, name=changeme, emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Thu Jan 15 13:52:41 2015 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Thu Jan 15 13:52:41 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=SE, ST=QQ, L=FrootTown, O=FrootOrg, OU=changeme, CN=server, name=changeme, emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Thu Jan 15 13:52:42 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Thu Jan 15 13:52:42 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Thu Jan 15 13:52:42 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Thu Jan 15 13:52:42 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Thu Jan 15 13:52:42 2015 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Thu Jan 15 13:52:42 2015 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]178.73.212.194:1201
Thu Jan 15 13:52:43 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1421358763,GET_CONFIG,,,
Thu Jan 15 13:52:44 2015 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Thu Jan 15 13:52:45 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,ifconfig-ipv6 2a00:1a28:1159:7::1004/64 2a00:1a28:1159:7::1,dhcp-option DNS 80.67.0.2,dhcp-option DNS 91.213.246.2,redirect-gateway def1,route-ipv6 2000::/3,tun-ipv6,route-gateway 46.246.9.225,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 160,ifconfig 46.246.9.230 255.255.255.224'
Thu Jan 15 13:52:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Thu Jan 15 13:52:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Thu Jan 15 13:52:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Thu Jan 15 13:52:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Thu Jan 15 13:52:45 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Thu Jan 15 13:52:45 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=1, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=1
Thu Jan 15 13:52:45 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1421358765,ASSIGN_IP,,46.246.9.230,
Thu Jan 15 13:52:46 2015 NETSH: C:\Windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ipv6 set address Local Area Connection 3 2a00:1a28:1159:7::1004 store=active
Thu Jan 15 13:52:46 2015 ERROR: netsh command failed: returned error code 1
Thu Jan 15 13:52:51 2015 NETSH: C:\Windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ipv6 set address Local Area Connection 3 2a00:1a28:1159:7::1004 store=active
Thu Jan 15 13:52:51 2015 ERROR: netsh command failed: returned error code 1
Thu Jan 15 13:52:56 2015 NETSH: C:\Windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ipv6 set address Local Area Connection 3 2a00:1a28:1159:7::1004 store=active
Thu Jan 15 13:52:56 2015 ERROR: netsh command failed: returned error code 1
Thu Jan 15 13:53:01 2015 NETSH: C:\Windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ipv6 set address Local Area Connection 3 2a00:1a28:1159:7::1004 store=active
Thu Jan 15 13:53:01 2015 ERROR: netsh command failed: returned error code 1
Thu Jan 15 13:53:05 2015 MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
Thu Jan 15 13:53:05 2015 NETSH: command failed
Thu Jan 15 13:53:05 2015 Exiting due to fatal error
```

Comment: Warning: route gateway is not reachable on any active network adapters... It looks like DHCP is failing to set an IP address on the connections adapter. This is usually caused by the Windows or a 3rd party Firewall preventing DHCP.

Comment: And I think your IP did change, in first file it was 178.73.212.201 and second 178.73.212.196

Comment: I will look at the firewall and DHCP settings in the router. As for those 2 IP addresses, Yes neither of those are my ISP IP address. And according to the program the IP address DOES change, but when I check my IP address online it is still my ISP address.

Comment: Is your VPN client 32-bit or 64-bit? Apparently, there is a bug in netsh and you need to use the 32-bit version. Google "netsh fails with error code 1" for very similar issues as yours.

Comment: Also, I would disable IPv6 on all my interfaces (if possible). I have always had issues with it on Windows even though I have never directly used it.

Comment: Ok, 32 bit version is connecting! I know that vpn tunnels (especially foreign ones) is common to slow down your internet speeds. I have 50mb/s download and frootvpn claims they have lots of 10gbit servers and When I connect I usually get 1 to 2 mb/s down with 200ms ping. Are there any settings in my router that could be slowing it down any? I want to squeeze as much as I can out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mahdi commented: Is your VPN client 32-bit or 64-bit? Apparently, there is a bug in netsh and you need to use the 32-bit version. Google "netsh fails with error code 1" for very similar issues as yours. – Mahdi

This was my problem. And because I cant select a comment as an answer I am putting it in here to hopefully benefit others.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error and in my case the solution was the following. Go to Network adapters -> TunnelTap, change IPv4 settings to assign IP address automatically. Apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this by un-intalling the TAP-9 network adapter in control panel, then reinstalling OpenVPN. I worked on this for days and was mot able to find much help on the net.

Hope this might help you as well